# How to avoid stack view from displaying it's content animated to bottom?

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, uiscrollview, uistackview

I am trying to display a `View Controller` that has a `scrollview` that in turn contains a `StackView`. This stack view has two subviews ie. an `UIImageView` & `UILabel`.

When I try to display the view controller by using push segue (with default navigation animation), it is displaying the contents of stack view as animated ie. with zoom out effect. I just want to display the content just as is with out animation.

Can someone help me ?

Thanks in advance .....

Comment: You'll have to explain what you mean by *"zoom out effect"*. Are you running any code when that view controller is shown?

Comment: @DonMag Thanks for the fast reply. Zoomed out effect means the image & label content displays animated. I am just doing designing with static content.

Comment: That sounds very odd. No code doing anything? Can you do an animated gif capture to show what's going on? Or, see [mcve].

Comment: Are you dynamically adding the subviews to the StackView in **viewDidAppear** ?
Because the default behaviour of stack is to animate when resized.

Comment: @DonMag Thanks for your support :). The issue got resolved magically when I changed the Stack view's Distribution property from Fill Proportionally to Fill.

Comment: @PrateekPande Thanks. I was not doing anything with the code. Only designing using storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the support.

Issue got resolved by myself. Regarding my screen, I have been using only storyboard for designing and no codes in `View controller` class.

I had set the `Distribution` property to `Fill Proportionally` and been displaying the view controller using `Push Segue (Show)` with default animation. When I removed the animation property to false, it was looking fine. But I had to have that push navigation animation.

Finally I changed the `Distribution` property to `Fill`, that did the magic !!! While checking the Stack View's behaviours, I came to know that the Stack View has got some animated listing nature by default.

If anyone can add more light to this nature of Stack view, would be beautiful. :)